# How can I see the sfdx version Number in the cli?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

So I am trying to see the exact version of the sfdx I am using any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple type in the command line interface `sfdx -v`

Answer (score 7):

[CLI Version Information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_troubleshoot_cli_version.htm) under [Troubleshoot Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_troubleshoot.htm) covers this

```
sfdx plugins --core      // Version of the CLI and all installed plug-ins
sfdx --version     // CLI version
```

The rest of the CLI commands are noted in [Salesforce CLI Command Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference.htm) as well as easily shown in the CLI with the following

`sfdx commands`

And it's always possible to add `--help` within a given command to understand any specific format/info about it. You can even just do:

`sfdx --help`

which outputs the following (also displays version).

```
Salesforce CLI

VERSION
  sfdx-cli/7.110.0 darwin-x64 node-v14.17.6

USAGE
  $ sfdx [COMMAND]

TOPICS
  alias    manage username aliases
  auth     authorize an org for use with the Salesforce CLI
  config   configure the Salesforce CLI
  force    tools for the Salesforce developer
  plugins  add/remove/create CLI plug-ins

COMMANDS
  autocomplete  display autocomplete installation instructions
  commands      list all the commands
  help          display help for sfdx
  plugins       list installed plugins
  update        update the sfdx CLI
  which         show which plugin a command is in
```